# Summernote turns message to html code when send to gmail

Tags: codeigniter, gmail, summernote

Hi everyone for now I've been working on a summernote textarea but when I send my email message to the gmail address it turn out to be something like this with html and not as text when you open your inbox:

```
& lt;p&g t ;test&lt;/p&gt
```

This is my contoller code:

```
$this->load->library('email'); // load email library
$this->email->set_newline ("\r\n");

$this->email->from($this->session->userdata('user_email'),$this->session-  >userdata('user_firstname').' '.$this->session->userdata('user_lastname'));
$this->email->to(set_value('message_email_to'));
$this->email->subject(set_value('subject'));
$this->email->message(set_value('message'));

if($this->email->send())
{
    $this->Compose_model->insert($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Create Record Success');
    redirect(BASE_URL.'tenant/compose');
}
else
{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

 $this->load->library('email'); 
 $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
 $config['mailtype'] = "html";
 $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
 $this->email->initialize($config);
```

put `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` on top of your message

Comment: thanks sir it works but still it has some html tags on it like the <p></> <b></b> etc , ,

Comment: you have to post here how the message variable initializing.

Comment: what do you mean sir? iam so sorry iam just a newbie and its my first time to make a email send , , ,T_T , , when i open the inbox it has some html tags like this : <p><span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline;">test</span></p>

Comment: try this $this->email->mailtype('html');

Comment: still not yet working sir . . when i type a message in the summernote then I put some italic or bold or underline then send it to the email address of the gmail, , and when I open the message in the inbox , it is in an HTML format and not as text

Comment: html tags are always included in the message

Comment: try this $message=htmlentities($message); and send this $message to email